# Installer Running When Application Launched As Different User

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have an installer built using WIX 3.0 and have a problem when trying to run the installed application as a different user than the user that ran the installer.

When I try to run the installed application as a different user than the user that ran the installer, the installer tries to run again (it's already installed at this point) and pops up some error dialogs and the application won't run.

I'm not sure what's going on, I thought it might be related to me not defining Product/@InstallScope. So I defined @InstallScope as "perMachine", but that didn't have any other effect.

Anyone seen this before that can give me some insight as to what can be done to fix it?

Here is the Package section:

```
<Package
  Id="*"
  Description="$(var.ProductName)"
  InstallerVersion="301"
  Compressed="yes"
  ReadOnly="yes"
  InstallPrivileges="elevated"
  InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

Comment: Do you get ICE warnings? Are you able to post a small .wxs file which shows this somewhere?

Comment: What do the error dialogs say?

Comment: The dialog is actually a popup from a custom action complaining about not being able to copy a file which it does during the normal instlal. After I close that dialog it looks like the installer is rolling back or something and then it pops up a "Problem with Shortcut" dialog saying "Fatal error during installation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the application event log ( filter by source MsiInstaller ).  It sounds like you have some per-user keypaths and the log will tell you what the component ID is.

Comment: That did it, thanks for the help.

My problem ended up being that I was using HKCU for a registry key for the program files menu shortcut. The event log indicated this was the problem. So I updated the key to HKMU which apparently handles both CU and LM installs.